# boost spirit and char16_t / UTF-16 support?

Tags: boost, boost-spirit, utf-16, lexer, char16-t

Is there any support, today or in the near future, for char16_t / UTF-16 in boost spirit?

I did try the word count lexer example using char16_t but ran into al sorts of compile errors.

Thanks,

Henry Roeland

Comment: Relevant: [How to match unicode characters with boost::spirit?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10478314/85371) and also [How to use Boost Spirit to parse Chinese(unicode utf-16)?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9871255/85371)

Comment: Should of known that answer...thanks for pointing it out. I already wrote my own lexer and parser using std::u16string. Now I face problems with the I/O of this std::u16string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Boost Spirit to parse Chinese(unicode utf-16)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852558/how-to-use-boost-spirit-to-parse-chineseunicode-utf-16)