# Replace lit with different string in boost spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I'm trying to parse a quoted string containing escape sequences using boost spirit. I'm looking for a way to replace escape sequences `\"` with the corresponding character (`"` in this case). So far I've come up with this.

`c_string %= lit('"') >> *(lit("\\\"")[push_back(_val, '"')] | (char_ - '"')) >> lit('"')`

with the replacement being done with

`lit("\\\"")[push_back(_val, '"')]`

however this seems to me quite clumsy and unreadable. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yep - YACC or Bison, you can use EBNF instead define rules using template metaprogramming :)

Comment: BTW, I think your definitions actually readable enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating: you can replace `"\\\""` with `'\\' >> lit('"')`, reformatting a bit:

```
c_string
    %= lit('"')
    >> *(
           '\\' >> lit('"')[push_back(_val, '"')]
         | (char_ - '"')
    )
    >> lit('"')
    ;
```

Now, you can do away with some of the `lit()` calls because they're implicit when invoking proto expressions in the Qi domain:

```
c_string
    %= '"'
    >> *(
           '\\' >> lit('"')[push_back(_val, '"')]
         | (char_ - '"')
    )
    >> '"'
    ;
```

Next up, `lit(ch)[push_back(_val, ch)]` is just a clumsy way to say `char_(ch)`:

```
c_string = '"'
    >> *( '\\' >> char_('"') | (char_ - '"') )
    >> '"';
```

> Note now we don't have the kludge of `%=` either (see [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)) and you can leave the `phoenix.hpp` include(s)

Finally, you can have a more optimized `char_ - char_(xyz)` by saying `~char_(xyz)`:

```
c_string = '"' >> *('\\' >> char_('"') | ~char_('"')) >> '"';
```

Now, you're not actually parsing C-style strings here. You're not handling escapes, so why not simplify:

```
c_string = '"' >> *('\\' >> char_|~char_('"')) >> '"';
```

> Note that now you actually parse backslash escapes, which you would otherwise not (you would parse `"\\"` into `"\\"` instead of `"\"`)

If you want to be more precise, consider handling escapes like e.g. [Handling utf-8 in Boost.Spirit with utf-32 parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273882/handling-utf-8-in-boost-spirit-with-utf-32-parser/19284681#19284681)

### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2df9ec96bedcd585)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    const qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string()> c_string
        = '"' >> *('\\' >> qi::char_|~qi::char_('"')) >> '"';

    for (std::string const input: {
            R"("")"               , // ""
            R"("\"")"             , // "\\\""
            R"("Hello \"world\"")", // "Hello \\\"world\\\""
        })
    {
        std::string output;
        if (parse(input.begin(), input.end(), c_string, output)) {
            std::cout << input << " -> " << output << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Failed: " << input << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"" -> 
"\"" -> "
"Hello \"world\"" -> Hello "world"
```

Comment: Added demo [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2df9ec96bedcd585)